# How can I delete and ARP cache entry on Ubuntu 14.04LTS via command-line?

Tags: command-line, networking, arp

This is my **ARP cache** on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64 bits (it is in spanish, sorry):

```
luis@Terminus:~$ arp -a
Windu- (192.168.11.100) en ac:22:0b:51:dd:33 [ether] en eth0
Router- (192.168.11.1) en 00:24:a5:0e:a8:42 [ether] en eth0
Bizancio- (192.168.11.108) en 00:0a:e4:a0:7f:78 [ether] en eth0
Virtuancio- (192.168.11.160) en 08:00:27:51:b1:70 [ether] en eth0
```

If I try to **delete** some entry:

```
luis@Terminus:~$ sudo arp -d 192.168.11.108
[sudo] password for luis:
```

No error. But immediately after that:

```
luis@Terminus:~$ arp -a
Windu- (192.168.11.100) en ac:22:0b:51:dd:33 [ether] en eth0
Router- (192.168.11.1) en 00:24:a5:0e:a8:42 [ether] en eth0
Bizancio- (192.168.11.108) en <incompleto> en eth0
Virtuancio- (192.168.11.160) en 08:00:27:51:b1:70 [ether] en eth0
```

This is: **nothing has been deleted**.
The ARP state keeps the same after some minutes.

Same results with `ip` command:

```
luis@Terminus:~$ sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all
192.168.11.100 dev eth0 lladdr ac:22:0b:51:dd:33 ref 1 used 0/0/0 probes 0 DELAY
192.168.11.1 dev eth0 lladdr 00:24:a5:0e:a8:42 ref 1 used 24/19/19 probes 1 REACHABLE
192.168.11.108 dev eth0 lladdr 00:0a:e4:a0:7f:78 used 145/131/115 probes 4 STALE
192.168.11.160 dev eth0 lladdr 08:00:27:51:b1:70 used 1121/1116/450 probes 1 STALE

*** Round 1, deleting 4 entries ***
*** Flush is complete after 1 round ***
luis@Terminus:~$ arp -a
Windu- (192.168.11.100) en ac:22:0b:51:dd:33 [ether] en eth0
Router- (192.168.11.1) en <incompleto> en eth0
Bizancio- (192.168.11.108) en <incompleto> en eth0
Virtuancio- (192.168.11.160) en <incompleto> en eth0
```

How can I **delete** any or all of the ARP cache entries?

Comment: The incompletes mean that they are removed.  Just give them time to disappear unless something calls for them and adds them back.  See this answer http://serverfault.com/questions/476272/arp-detete-is-not-deleting-an-entry-merely-marks-entry-as-incomplete

Comment: Well, it was just a matter of understanding the behavior of the `arp` command output. You should write it down as an answer, @Terrance.

Comment: Thank you!  I have posted this as an answer for you.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is correct that you're using.  The incomplete status means that they are removed.  If you give them time, they will disappear.  If something on the network pings them or tries to access them, they will appear in the table again.

Another explanation can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/476272/arp-detete-is-not-deleting-an-entry-merely-marks-entry-as-incomplete).